# Why is persist in JPA clearing the existing data in the table row?

Tags: mysql, jpa

I am trying to update data to a mySQL database using JPA. I have no problem persisting data but flush will not work as expected. I retrieve the id for the login session, set that id (it is the primary key) along with setting the description field that I want merged to the database. I have debugged line by line through this method and all variables contain the expected values. Any ideas or suggestions to overcome this problem are appreciated.

```
    public String update() {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();   


    if(true){
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        String sessionEmail=Util.getEmail();
        //Create query to find user passwords matching the inputted name
        Query myQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM BusinessAccount u WHERE u.email=:email");
        myQuery.setParameter("email", sessionEmail);
        List<BusinessAccount> accounts=myQuery.getResultList();
        int intId=accounts.get(0).getId();
        businessAccount.setId(intId);
        String des=businessAccount.getDescription();
        businessAccount.setDescription(des);
        em.flush();
        addMessage(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                "User Registration Successful!", null));
        return "success";
    } 

    else {
        addMessage(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "User Registration Failed!", null));
        return "failure";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`merge()` persists **all** the state of the entity. Not just the non-null fields. I it wasn't, you would complain that you want to set some field to null and that `merge()` ignores it and leaves it as is.

So get an entity from the database, and modify it, instead of only gettings its ID, creating a new entity instance from scratch and only settings some of its fields.

Note that, if you get the entity and modify it inside a single transaction, you don't even have to call `merge()`: the new state will be made persistent automatically.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand your first point and it makes sense to me. However I'm not sure what you mean in your other 2 points. Could you give me an example of what you mean please. Thanks

Comment: @NiallKelly You should be using the query `SELECT u FROM...` rather than just getting the `id`. You can then use `List<BusinessAccount> accounts` rather than `List myId`. Now update your objects as required and `flush()`. You don't need to `merge()` and you should never (very rarely) query ids from the database. That is **the whole point** of ORM!

Comment: Sorry-I'm new to this site and didn't know that I could update my question up the top but have done so now. I don't understand what you are suggesting however as the solution so would be great if you could explain it a little more(I'm new to programming and am not fully understanding your explanation). I have created a list of objects as you suggested. I'm not sure how to link the 'description' string to the correct row in the database without referencing the id   field related to the object. Could you explain it a little more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NiallKelly, when using JPA (or any ORM) you must think in objects (entities) as a whole when querying and modifying. That allows versioning, caching and even structuring better your application. What Boris was saying about the ID is exactly that. Get the whole object, modify what you need (Id and Description attributes) and merge/persist it.